# Import from Excel

Tags: c#, ms-access, sharepoint-2007, excel-2007

I use Access 2007, SQL Server 2005 and 2008, and C#.net with VS20010.

I need to validate, then import an Excel workbook that has been posted to a SP document library. I wrote the program using VBA in A2k7 so I could get it working, get all my thoughts together, etc. Shortly, I'm going to start converting it to C# so I can run it on a scheduled basis from my SQL Server agent. Authentication may be fun, we'll see.

In my Access VBA program, I use a simple statement to create a multi-dimensional array of "variants". This allows me to test every single cell for the correct type before I try to assign it to a local variable. Certain cells must be numeric. Others, I use as strings, even if they're numeric. Since the data may be hand-entered, I could see virtually any content in the cells...one of the reasons I don't just import it, since most import vehicles (ACCESS, SSIS) use Excel's determination as to the column's "type".

```
    '
'   Get the range of used cells from the worksheet and stuff it into an array
'
xlApp.visible = False                   'Don't let the workbook be shown
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(URL)    'Open the workbook
Set xlSH = xlWB.Worksheets(1)           'Must be the first worksheet in the workbook
HandleMessages 1, 0, 1, "Working on Workbook " & xlWB.NAME & ", Worksheet " & xlSH.NAME
Set xlRA = xlSH.UsedRange               'xlRA is the range of cells in the first workbook that are "USED"
strSheetArray = xlRA                    'This sets an array of variants to the two dimensional range xlRA
```

So, going to C#, what do I do about the lack of a non-typed "variant"? How do I proceed? Anyone done it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dynamic` in C# 4.0.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

> The type is a static type, but an object of type dynamic bypasses
>   static type checking. In most cases, it functions like it has type
>   object. At compile time, an element that is typed as dynamic is
>   assumed to support any operation. Therefore, you do not have to be
>   concerned about whether the object gets its value from a **COM API**, from
>   a dynamic language such as IronPython, from the HTML Document Object
>   Model (DOM), from reflection, or from somewhere else in the program.
>   However, if the code is not valid, errors are caught at run time.

The link shows examples of using `dynamic` with Excel.